# Delta function and Laplace transformation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, dirac-delta, step-function

l. (5) If y(t) solves y" + y = δ (tーpi/2) , y(0) = 0, y,(0) = 1, then at t= pi laplace is (a) -1 (b) 1 (c) -2 (d)2 (e) 0
ANWER=1
[image]

My question is when i plugin y=pi before changing into -cos(t) i get the answer as 2 and i don't understand how changing it makes a  difference or why i even had to change it?

Comment: Looks like you have an algebra issue as they should produce the same thing, see [*Wolfram Alpha*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=evaluate+sin(t)+%2B+sin(t-pi%2F2)+unitstep(t+-+pi%2F2)+at+t+%3D+pi). Note: $$\sin \pi = 0, \sin(\pi - \pi/2) = 1, u(\pi - \pi/2) = 1 \implies \sin \pi + \sin(\pi - \pi/2) u(\pi - \pi/2) = 0 + 1 \times 1 = 1 $$

Comment: T h a n k y o u!!!